# Django. Postfix. send_mail() works fine in shell, but not in view

Tags: django

When in shell i do:

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('hi', 'hi', 'hi@hi.ru', ['maxkoroteev@mail.ru'])
1
```

Everything is fine, i've got the mail.

But when I do it in view using browser (django server or gunicorn), i have no errors and no emails

It is about rights i think. But what exactly should I do?

Big thx for help!

P.S. I am using Centos

Comment: Can you share your view code?